# undefined variable row in edit text

Tags: php, html

this code works, it edit the text that i want to edit, but there's an error show that i declared a undefined variable row.

```
<?php
    require("dbc.php");



    if( isset( $_GET['edit']))
    {
    $no = $_GET['edit'];
    $res = mysql_query("SELECT* From description_tbl Where No = '$no'");
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($res); 

    }
    if( isset($_POST['phome']))
    {
    $phome = $_POST['phome'];
    $No = $_POST['id'];
    $sql ="UPDATE Description_tbl set Describ = '$phome' Where No = '$No'";
    $res = mysql_query($sql) or die("could not update".mysql_error());
    echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content = '0;url = bHome.php'>";
    }
    ?>

    <form action ="edit.php" method = "POST">
    <textarea rows="10" cols="70" name="phome"><?php echo $row[1];?></textarea>
    <input type = "hidden" name = "id" value = "<?php echo $row[0];?>">
    <br>
    <input type = "submit" value = "Save">
    </form>
```

Comment: Sidenote: It's not a good idea to use resembling variables such as `$No` and `$no`; it just leaves room for mistakes/confusion; *really.*

Comment: yr code seems so secure..

Comment: DO NOT use unsanitized variables in your SQL! See: SQL injection

Answer (score 3):

I believe it is due to the `$row` you echo in the form, you need to check if they are set as well:

```
<textarea rows="10" cols="70" name="phome">
         <?php echo isset($row[1]) ? $row[1] : '';?>
</textarea>
<input type="hidden" name = "id" value = "<?php echo isset($row[0]) ? $row[0] : '';?>">
```

When your form is not in edit mode these variables are undefined since the if block does not run.

Comment: The power of ternary operators; love 'em. Good answer btw ;)

Comment: Pretty hard, for sure.

Answer (score 1):

I'm still a newbie in Web Programming but I guess the reason why that error occurs is when the first conditional statement is not executed.

But if the first if statement is executed or true then your code will be fine.

Answer (score 0):

I FIXED IT! I guess had exactly the same probem as you. Well, this worked for me.

I'm assuming `if( isset( $_GET['edit']))` is for getting the id info from `edit.php?edit=No` ("No" is what I refer to as id, as the variable you use is `$No`, usually an integer, probably a unique value in the respective table).

After a lot of research and losing time I just tried this. Add this to the `<form>`:

Change

```
<form action ="edit.php" method = "POST">
```

to

```
<form action ="edit.php?edit=<?php echo $row[0];?>" method = "POST">
```

In this case you use `$row[0]` but it could be another position in the row instead of 0, depending of the unique value in your sql table.

I'm guessing (not that expert in html forms) but I think when you submit your form the page refreshes somehow (`form action = "edit.php..."`) and loses the `$_GET` info (No, id) so you must add the `?edit=No` part to the form action so the whole thing can get the little number again and not get lost in what row in your table is it working on.